# Is there any automatic way to use specific font specifically for math?

Tags: fonts

I am trying to mimic the look of Wolfram|Alpha, which uses the Bitstream fonts Charter (for math and some text) and Vera Sans (for most text and things like units after numbers). Is there any *automatic* way to achieve this in a formatted notebook (where I am using inline math) without manual changing the font of each portion? For a better idea, take the following screenshot:
[image: Math and text both using charter font]

`Fullform` due to request:

```
 \!\(TraditionalForm\`\(\*SqrtBox[\(200\)]\[LineSeparator]\n 200 = 2\\ 2\\ 2\\ 5\\ 5, \\ or\\ \*SuperscriptBox[\(2\), \(2\)]\\ \*SuperscriptBox[\(5\), \(2\)]\\ 2\\ \((when\\ separated\\ into\\ squares)\), \\ so\\ \*SqrtBox[\(200\)] = \(\((2\\ 5)\)\\ \*SqrtBox[\(2\)] = 10\\ \(\*SqrtBox[\(2\)]\(.\)\)\)\)\)
```

Is there a way to automatically render the text in Vera while keepin the math in Charter without having to manually format each piece?

Comment: We would need to know the `FullForm` of your screenshot to give advice

Comment: ``Sqrt[200] 200=2 2 2 5 5,or 2^2 5^2 2 (when separated into squares),so \ Sqrt[200]=(2 5) Sqrt[2]=10 Sqrt[2].``

Comment: Eric look up `FullForm` in the docs. IMO this is what is needed to know how to approach your problem

Comment: Uh, whenever I attempt to copy the output of ``FullForm``, Mathematica crashes. O_o

Comment: Re: crash, that's disturbing.  Nevertheless please try copying the output of `FullForm` as **Plain Text** and see if it works.

Comment: It works. Thanks @Mr.Wizard. Updated question with the output of ``FullForm``.

Comment: Related: [(13785)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13785/121), [(16154)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16154/121),
[(27117)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27117/121)

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate because my Accepted answer is merely derivative of Mike Honeychurch's answer therein.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question you have a Text Cell with inline Cells containing math expressions.  The styling can be controlled with [style sheets](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateANewStyleInAStylesheet.html) applied to the styles `Text` and `InlineCell`.  For example:

[image]

Produced by:

[image]

Which has the Cell code:

```
Cell[StyleData["InlineCell"],
 MenuSortingValue->10000,
 FontFamily->"Comic Sans MS",
 FontSize->17,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontSlant->"Italic",
 FontVariations->{"StrikeThrough"->False,
 "Underline"->False},
 FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 1]]

Cell[StyleData["Text"],
 FontFamily->"Times New Roman",
 FontSize->16,
 FontWeight->"Plain",
 FontSlant->"Plain",
 FontVariations->{"StrikeThrough"->False,
 "Underline"->False},
 FontColor->RGBColor[0.6, 0.4, 0.2]]
```