# Equations in text cell in wrong format

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting

In order to type an equation in a text cell one presses Ctrl+9 and then you get a highlighted region into which you type an equation.  Here is an example

[image: Text cell with equation]

The problem here is that the equation is in an Arial font. Equations should appear in `TraditionalForm`. If I go to a new cell make it `TranditionalForm` and type I get this:

[image: Traditional form cell]

This is what I want (except that it is annoyingly in bold which I have removed).

The real mystery is if I do `ShowExpression` on the text cell I get

[image: Internals of text cell]

Note that the Cell within the Cell containing the equation has "FormatType"  "TraditionalForm". So the question: why is the equation in the text cell not in `TraditioalForm`?

If I do `ShowExpression` on the equation in the `TraditionalForm` cell I get this

[image: Internals of traditional form cell]

This is almost the same except it has an extra `StyleBox`. Has this been missed out? This is version 12.2 but this problem has been around for several versions.

How do I fix this?

Some similar question asked before are [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25997/12558) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3510/12558) but are not quite the same.

Comment: you can change the font with the Style command https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FontFamily.html

Comment: @acacia Yes thanks,  but how do I automatically get it changed within a text cell?

Comment: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/402640

Comment: @acacia Again note that this does not address how to change a format within a text cell. Note you make a text cell by pressing Alt+7 and then you can type text and then put in equations using Ctrl+9. I am talking about formatting a cell within a cell.